# what adjustments i can do to run this script perfectly?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/dan/PycharmProjects/chromedriver.exe") driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/login.php")  
# identify username, password and signin elements driver.find_element_by_name("LoginID").send_keys("3480199")  driver.find_element_by_name("NewPass").send_keys("12")  driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
time.sleep(1.0)
driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/map.php?Map=14")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("center").click()
time.sleep(1.0)
if driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/blockquote[@class='error']"):

    driver.refresh()

elif driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']"):

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/form[1]/blockquote[@class='success']/p[@class='center'][2]/a").click()
while True:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/form[1]/blockquote[@class='success']/p[@class='center'][2]/a").click()
 Score = 8,363
 if  score = 7,856,000
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/blockquote[@class='success']/strong"):
     print("7,856,000")
```

the script runs perfectly till these lines

```
driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/map.php?Map=14")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("center").click()
time.sleep(1.0)
```

afterwards it shows error or doeesnt run most of the codes.
my aim is to make a script that will only stop if i get the score 7,856,000

these are the complex steps in which i get stuck

if i end getting these two pages
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/blockquote[@class='error']")`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t95VJ.jpg

or

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']"):`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjTgS.jpg

the page should refresh until i get this page

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/form[1]/blockquote[@class='success']/p[@class='center'][2]/a").click()`

upon getting to this page it should click to the blue link "Submit to safri"etc

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSjgY.jpg

after submitting i would get some kind of score here

as shown in this image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUeuP.jpg

Answer (score 1):

```
While True:
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='body']/div[@id='inner']/form[1]/blockquote[@class='success']/p[@class='center'][2]/a")
        elem.click()
        break
    except:
        driver.refresh()
```

Why not just refresh until that element pops up.

Comment: It looks for the element if it's not there it refreshes and then clicks it if it's there and breaks out the loop.

Comment: elem.click()---- shows except or finally expected error break except:----- shows statement expected ,found py:except keyboard error driver.refresh() it shows error in these lines

Comment: I added a time.sleep() which should be changed out for a webdriver wait. What error did you get>?

Comment: i am getting error here shown in this image https://imgur.com/uujRNjU

Comment: Oh your identation is off.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Put the break in the try.

Comment: ok thanks it worked with spaces etc.. what loop or steps should i add so this continues till i get the score 7,856,000